# How do I get the max count of queryable keys from a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id": "123", // 1
  "parent1": {
    "child1": "234",  // 2
    "child2": {
      "grandchild1": "345",  // 3
      "grandchild2": {
        "greatgrand1": "456" // 4
      }
    },
    "child3": [
      {
        "grandchild1": "567", // 5
        "grandchild2": {
          "greatgrand1": "678", // 6
          "greatgrand2": {
            "greatgrand1": "789" // 7
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "parent2": [
    {
      "child1": "567", // 8
      "child2": {
        "grandchild1": "678", // 9
        "grandchild2": {
          "greatgrand1": "789"  // 10
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The count would return 10 for this document. I have other documents of varying size and depth. I would then like it to compare and return the largest count.

I have tried doing various forms of $objectToArray, but haven't found one that works.